# How to close your webcam with cv2 working in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, webcam, opencv

I am working with cv2 and when I want to release and close my window my program got the error. How can I close my python window?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    cv2.imshow('Raw Webcam Feed', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-798f375b211f> in <module>
      1 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      2 while cap.isOpened():
----> 3     ret, frame = cap.read()
      4     cv2.imshow('Raw Webcam Feed', frame)
      5 

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are asking, but you specify :

```py
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

So you should quit cv2 by hiting "q" on your keyboard, in order to break the loop and release the camera. Is that what you're doing ?

Comment: Weird... Your code works perfectly when i run it...